# Getting ECONNRESET response using node's http.get function

Tags: node.js, express

I finally figured out what was causing this problem and didn't find any direct answers online, so I thought I'd post an answer (below).  Anyway, here's the problem:

I have a simple node app running on port 3000.  I was trying out some database connection pooling, and I wanted to load test it to make sure it was working the way I expected.  I installed siege and tried:

`$ siege -c 10 -r 10 -b http://localhost:3000`

I got a `Connection reset by peer` error.  So I tried reducing the number of connections:

`$ siege -c 1 -r 1 -b http://localhost:3000`

Same problem.  I thought maybe it was a problem with siege, so I tried nperf and got a `ECONNRESET` error.  Same with artillery.

The weird thing is that I could connect using curl, telnet, and the web browser and got a valid response.

I tried logging errors in the express app, but it never seemed to receive a request.  I tried monitoring network traffic using `nettop`, but it never showed a connection using siege or nperf (though it did using curl).

I wrote a client app to connect using the same method that nperf uses (node's `http.get` function), and got the same `ECONNRESET` response.

I wrote a simple express app running on port 3001 and it worked fine!  I tried commenting out most of the lines in my port 3000 app so it was basically the same as my 3001 app, but it still didn't work.  I was beginning to suspect that webpack was doing something strange, and then finally started to realize...see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there's another program on port 3000!

So, I ran:

`$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"`

and I found an old VM I'd forgotten to halt, that had port 3000 exposed (another project).  I shut it down and everything worked great!

I thought node warned if a port was being used, but for some reason it didn't notice this one.

Anyway, if you're getting a similar error, do a port scan!